# Can't set default kernel in grub2

Tags: linux, grub2

Can't set default kernel in grub2.
Tried the following steps:

```
set GRUB_DEFAULT --> saved in /etc/default/grub  
grub-set-default --> set the proper kernel
```

In the file `/boot/grub/grubenv` the entry `saved_entry` is set correct.
Furthermore when I tried to reboot once with `grub-reboot` it is also not the proper kernel.
I checked the `grub.cfg` if the proper kernel and initramfs are in the correct menuentry.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the command

```
grub2-set-default <n>
```

where *n* is the GRUB line referencing the kernel you want to boot as default.

Comment: imho the command is version independent. I can't find a reference in the man-page or grub-manual.